# Atomically increment an integer in a document in Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

How can I atomically increment an integer in a document in Azure DocumentDB?

The increment operation must be atomic in the presence of concurrent writers. No lost increments are allowed (they would be possible in a naive read-modify-write algorithm).

Comment: What do you mean by "they would be possible in a naive read-modify-write algorithm"? Every document has an Etag and any changes sent with non-current Etag would be rejected (HTTP 412) [see here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-faq/#develop)

Comment: Thanks. That would be answer. If you don't want to add it I'll add it myself later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-faq/#develop):

> How does DocumentDB provide concurrency?
>
> DocumentDB supports optimistic concurrency control (OCC) through HTTP
>   entity tags or ETags. Every DocumentDB resource has an ETag, and
>   DocumentDB clients include their latest read version in write
>   requests. If the ETag is current, the change is committed. If the
>   value has been changed externally, the server rejects the write with a
>   "HTTP 412 Precondition failure" response code. Clients must read the
>   latest version of the resource and retry the request.

One can use this property to implement a [CAS loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap):

```
 while (true) {
  var existingDoc = ReadDoc();

  existingDoc.Int++;

  try {
   WriteDoc(existingDoc);
   break;
  }
  catch { //Concurrency violation
   continue;
  }
 }
```

Also note that transactions in Azure DocumentDB run on a snapshot of the data (Snapshot Isolation).

BTW: If you would like to do something a bit more automated (auto increment when someone modifies a document) you can use a trigger and separated collection for current value of an integer. Triggers are executed in the same transaction so it would be consistent and automated.