# Executing DocumentDb stored procedures in parallel

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

Can documentDb stored procedures run in parallel and update the same object? Will documentDb process them sequentially?

Consider the following scenario.

I have an app and I have 10000 coins to give away to my users when they complete a task. And I have the following object

```
{
    remainingPoints: 10000
}
```

I have a stored procedure that subtracts 10 points from this object and adds them to the users' points.

Now lets say 10 users complete the task at the same time and I call the stored procedure 10 times at the same time, will DocDb execute them sequentially? Or will I have to execute the stored procedures sequentially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar questions when I first started using DocumentDB and got good answers here and in email from the DocumentDB product managers. Quoting:

> Stored procedures ... get an isolated snapshot of the database for transactional support. The snapshot reflects the current state of the world (no stale data) at the time the sproc begins execution (strongly consistent).
>
> Caveat – since stored procedures are operating on a snapshot,  you can still get a stale read in a sproc if a new write come in from the outside world during execution.
>
> Also, stored procedures will ALWAYS read their owns writes.
>
> Sprocs are DocumentDB’s mechanism for multi-document transactions. Sproc writes are committed when a sproc successfully complete execution. If an exception is thrown, all work done in a sproc gets rolled back.
>
> So if two are sprocs are running concurrently, they won’t see eachother’s writes.
>
> If both sprocs happen to write to the same document (replace) – then the 2nd one will fail due to an etag mismatch when it attempts to commit writes.

From that, I went forward with my design making sure to use ETags in my writes as @Julian suggests. I also automatically retry up to 3 times each sproc execution to handle the case where they fail due to parallel operations among other reasons. In practice, I've never exceed the 3 retries (except in cases where my sproc had a bug) and I rarely even get a single retry.

I assume from the behavior that I observe that it sends each new sproc execution to a different replica until it runs out of replicas and then it queues them for sequential execution, so it's a hybrid of parallel and serial execution.

One other tip that I learned through experimentation is that you are better off doing pure read operations (no writes and no significant aggregation) client-side rather than in a sproc when you are on a heavily loaded system. I assume the advantage is because DocumentDB can satisfy different reads from different replicas in parallel. I have modularized my sproc code using the [`expandScript`](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/src/expandScript.coffee) functionality of [documentdb-utils](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#support-for-require-in-server-side-scripts) to make sure that I use the exact same code for write validation, intra-document consistency, and derived fields both client-side and server-side, which is possible using node.js. Even if you are mostly .NET, you may want to use `expandScripts` to build your sprocs in a modular DRY way. You'll still need to run node.js in your build process to pre-process your sprocs or use Edge.NET (node running inside of .NET) to do so on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation @Larry :)

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the consistency you have choose for your collection. But the idea is that DocumentDb handle concurrency using etag and executes stored procedure on a snapshot of a document version, and commit the result only if the execution succeed.

See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-faq/#develop

This thread may help too: [Atomically increment an integer in a document in Azure DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805666/atomically-increment-an-integer-in-a-document-in-azure-documentdb)

Comment: Julien, I do not believe that the current consistency level plays a role in sproc execution - only in client-side operations. All sprocs are executed in an isolated snapshot and all operations either all work or all fail. As you suggest, you still use ETags for all read-write operations against the same documents.